# ajax call with post returning nothing

Tags: php, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "read_files.php",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success(data){
        fileContainer.innerHTML = data;
        containerPopUp.style.display = "none";        

        const fileUploaders =Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".file-uploader"));

        fileUploaders.map((fileUploader)=>{
            fileUploader.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
                const file_id = e.target.parentNode.childNodes[1].getAttribute("value");
                console.log("data coming from js ",file_id);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "delete_file.php",
                    method:"post",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    data : {"fileId" : file_id},
                    processData: false , 
                    success(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                })
            })
        })        


    }

})
```

and this is the PHP code

```
<?php
$img_id = $_POST["fileId"];

echo "data ->" . $img_id;
?>
```

Comment: `contentType: false,` ??

Comment: should I remove it?

Comment: You should probably look it and the other params up in the manual and use what is required and remove what is not

Comment: not all heroes wear caps ❤
thanks for the advice

Comment: "Returning nothing" meaning what? Which ajax call? You have two. I assume it's the first (outer) one, since you're showing us a php that suits `read_files` more than `delete_file`, but it's not good to make assumptions.

Comment: @El_Vanja I am not quite familiar with ajax so I don't know what for example contentType do I only know the data and url and success method

It's now fixed after I removed 
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,

I don't know why but it's working now.

my problem was that the $_POST["fileId"] returns nothing and I didn't know why that happened.